# Custom Metadata Command Returnning Incorrect Data

Tags: metadata, cli, state

I have written a command that exports the metadata at the CLI which /should/ duplicate the results of `state_getMetadata`.

Full Source Code: https://github.com/LibertyDSNP/frequency/blob/main/node/cli/src/export_metadata_cmd.rs

However the output does not match the `state_getMetadata`. For example, frequency does not currently use or import the XCM pallets. `state_getMetadata` does NOT have any of the events from those pallets as expected. However, the metadata from the CLI DOES have those events.

This is because the command is can pull from the chain state.

How can I make sure that the `export_metadata_cmd.rs` never creates or uses the data from prior state?

In effect I always want to run this cli command with `--tmp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found one fix: https://github.com/LibertyDSNP/frequency/pull/987

This uses `impl CliConfiguration` to force the base_path to a temp directory. Feels like it shouldn't need this, but it works.

```rust
impl CliConfiguration for ExportMetadataCmd {
  // We never want to use any stored data. Always just use fresh.
  fn base_path(&self) -> Result<Option<sc_service::BasePath>, sc_cli::Error> {
    Ok(Some(sc_service::BasePath::new_temp_dir()?))
  }
}
```